# Running a junit class file from command line

Tags: java, selenium, junit4

I tried running a junit class file from command line, I am getting the following error:

```
 D:\saurabh>java -cp D:\testing\selenium_scripts\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore D:\saurabh\NewMercury.class
JUnit version 4.4
Could not find class: D:\saurabh\NewMercury.class

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)


D:\saurabh>dir /p
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4C6B-63F6

 Directory of D:\saurabh

06/24/2015  06:09 PM    <DIR>          .
06/24/2015  06:09 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/27/2015  04:42 PM         7,187,628 export.dat
06/24/2015  05:51 PM             3,302 NewMercury.class
03/11/2015  07:32 PM           148,696 PortQryV2.exe
```

The class file exists, but still its showing the error "Could not find class: D:\saurabh\NewMercury.class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D:\saurabh\NewMercury.class is invalid way.

Correct command to execute from D:\saurabh dir is :

```
D:\saurabh>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scripts\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore NewMercury
```

Now if you are running command:

C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin\com\tests>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scri
pts\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore NewMercury

**Run it as below:**
C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scripts\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.tests.NewMercury

//Running junit test(command-line) format:

- java -cp .;path_to_junit_jar\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore you_class_with_package
- path_to_junit_jar - D:\testing\selenium_scripts
- you_class_with_package - com.tests.NewMercury i.e. Considering NewMercury.java has a declaration "package com.tests"

Comment: I am still facing an issue, posted it below

Comment: C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin\com\tests>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scr
pts\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.tests.NewMercury
JUnit version 4.4
Could not find class: com.tests.NewMercury

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)

Answer (score 0):

I moved a bit ahead, but still facing this issue:
This is the original class file which is working fine from eclipse

```
C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin\com\tests>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scri
pts\junit-4.4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore NewMercury
JUnit version 4.4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NewMercury (wrong nam
e: com/tests/NewMercury)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:44)
```

Comment: Do we need to give the path of the selenium jar file also in the class path?
selenium-firefox-driver-2.45.0.jar , selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar

Comment: I have shared it below

Comment: I am using standalone jar, it is containing all the dependencies (Junit, firefox), but still its unable to find the class file 

C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin\com\tests>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scri
pts\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.tests.N
ewMercury.class
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: com.tests.NewMercury.class

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)

Comment: When not using com.tests it is able to identify the class

C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin\com\tests>java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scri
pts\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore NewMercury
JUnit version 4.11
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: NewMercury (wrong nam
e: com/tests/NewMercury)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: -->`cd C:\Users\352720\workspace\Test\bin`
-->`java -cp .;D:\testing\selenium_scripts\selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.tests.NewMercury`

Comment: @Rajesh: It worked Rajesh :).
But I am also looking for some result file , from where results can be captured

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for NewMercury.java:

```
package com.tests;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class NewMercury {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.in";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testNewMercury() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("mercury travels");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mercury Travels: Flight, Cheap Air Tickets , Hotels, Holiday ...")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```